# Are there any third party Google Contacts editors?

Tags: google-contacts

Are there any third party Google Contacts editors? I really dislike the editors that Google provides.

Answer (score 1):

1. Google does have an open API for you to use if you wanted to write a script to edit/clean your contacts yourself.
2. Assuming you're not interested in that though, I'll explain what I do. I use a mac and I use the built in address book application to manage my contacts. This application syncs with google.

   In combination with the sync from my local address book/iCloud, I also use an app I picked up in the app store called [Contacts Cleaner](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contacts-cleaner/id411369012?mt=12) which helps me keep the data clean, dup free, and well-formatted.
3. Have you looked at products like [Gist](http://gist.com)? Have you [seen this guide to improving Google Contacts](http://lifehacker.com/5499575/the-complete-guide-to-fixing-google-contacts)?

Comment: Gist.com was [shuttered](http://blog.gist.com/2012/08/15/gist-the-next-chapter/) on September 15, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can access and edit Google Contacts with any device/programm that uses Mail for Exchange protocol (it is Microsoft's protocol). For example my mobile phone supports Mail for Exchange, and whenever I update contacts on my phone it is synced with Google Contacts.